# Copy ID column from List A to TASK List B using Workflow in SPD 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have created approval workflow in SPD 2007.

Step 1) User submit the form --> Workflow setup on create a new item on Request Form
Step 2) Workflow kickoff and create a tasks and assign to various teams.
Step 3) User fillout the feedback on assigned task and submit

Requirement. :  When User submit the form then form generate it's own ID (interanl id). 
                Workflow generate the new tasks then it assign interal ID to each tasks.

In Task list. I would like to add column that represent the Original Request ID from Request Form. So, in my report, I can show which requests are pending or so..

Example,

Customer Requests List

Request ID                  Customer Name            Customer Phone#      etc....
222                           ABC Company               111-222-3333

Workflow Tasks

Request ID     Title                       Assigned To                  Status
222         Approval to add new customer  John Smith                   Pending

I would like to populate Request ID column in TASK from Customer Request List [ Column ID ] without writing code. Is it possible ?

Something link this...

Task List
ID       Assign To      Link                    Request ID 
1         Sales          ABC  (Hyperlink)        100
2         Marketing      ABC   (Hyperlink)       100
3         Audit          ABC   (Hyperlink)       100

I would apprecaite your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already answered your own question. In your workflow, add another step to update each task's `RequestID` field to be Current Item -> ID.

Comment: Actually, problem is in SPD when I create a workflow on Request List --> When new iteam created ... I don't have access to TASK list field ( Request ID) . How can I update the request ID in the task list ?

Comment: Hi Kit, Yes I am creating task using workflow. 1) Workflow setup on Create item on Approval Form. 2) When someone submit the form, workflow kicksoff and create a tasks under the task list. Example Request Form ID Summary Details 100 ABC Test Task List ID Assign To Link 1 Sales ABC (Hyperlink) 2 Marketing ABC (Hyperlink) 3 Audit ABC (Hyperlink) I would like know if I can get the ID (100) from Request Form inside the Task List 
Task List
ID       Assign To      Link                    Request ID 
1         Sales          ABC  (Hyperlink)        100

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific... are you using the "Create List Item" workflow action?

Comment: Kit, I am using Sharepoint Desinger --> Workflow Actions --> "Assign a Form to a Group"   --> When someone submit the new form this workflow kicksoff and create a tasks under the Task list and assign to various teams.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you correctly (which i may not have so apologies in advanced if so) you could do this:

- Create The Task List in the TASK LIST B with a lookup field (linked to TASK LIST A) in the task that you set to the ID of the the current item
- When you have created the item you will get the ID in a variable of the list item you have created - set a lookup field (linked to TASK LIST B) in TASK LIST A to the 'create' variable from creating the TASK LIST B item

This will give you a link between each task list item within the task list item (because of the lookup fields' functionality) and you will have made a link between the two...

Hope this makes sense and helps out in some way...